# Is ubuntu available in Tamil?

Tags: language-support, interface

Is ubuntu available in Tamil? 
If yes give me the link to download the language interface

Answer (score 3):

There is tamil in ubuntu ..Goto settings->language support-> install or remove language -> check Tamil ->apply

[image]